# Best approach to web service powered by a daemon

Tags: linux, web-services

I am relatively new to web services and am wondering what the standard "best approach" is. Basically, the way things work is I need to have a task running the background constantly.

The the web service will connect to the daemon and return with an appropriate response. Currently, the communication is over unix domain sockets (Linux is the expected server platform).

Is this the "right" way to do this? Or is there a more proper way to have a background task that your web-server is based on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty much the best practice. You may be familiar with this pattern from other web applications: The daemon is frequently a database. :)

Comment: Yea, I figured so much, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.